# Maven jar-with-dependencies - any violation of distribution license?

Tags: apache-2.0, distribution, java, dependencies

I have a Java application that uses some Apache common libraries (Apache 2.0 license).

I wanted to distribute it as a single fat jar (maven builds a single jar with dependencies packaged in a single jar) with my classes along with the OSS classes.

Are there any issues in doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you preserve the NOTICE file(s) when distributing your binary, what you're doing is OK per the Apache License.

For instance, [this is the NOTICE file](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/NOTICE.txt) for the current Commons Lang.  You would need to ensure its contents are available to the consumer.

Comment: FWIW, There are possibly some caveats though beyond Apache-licensed code: there is no such thing as static linking in Java, but what if you have included a modified LGPL-licensed library? in this case this is IMHO akin to static linking and the corresponding LGPL terms would kick in. Another question is if a fat jar repacking is considered a modification or not.

Comment: While that's a fair point, the question at hand is specific to an Apache licensed project.

Comment: exactly, hence why I upvoted you and only added a comment